# Linq to XML Subquery

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Event ID="1"..... >
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
</Event>
<Event ID="2"..... >
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
</Event>
<Event ID="3"..... >
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
    <SubEvent update="DATETIME" />
</Event>
```

I want to remove the "Event" elements where ALL update attribute in the SubEvent are lower than the provided DATETIME.

If, for example one DATETIME is higher, the element should NOT be removed.

Comment: Why do you think that? Have you measured that it is too slow?

Comment: And how do you think LINQ to XML is working? With magic? :) It also loops over the elements.

Comment: I realize that my last comment probably didn't help you, so here is some additional advice: Try to reduce the looping as much as possible. For example, if the first `SubEvent` of an `Event` is greater than the provided date, you can stop the processing of that `Event`. There is no need to loop over the rest of its `SubEvent` elements. But other than that, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply select all those events and remove them from document:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
xdoc.Descendants("Event")
    .Where(e => e.Elements().All(se => (DateTime)se.Attribute("update") < date))
    .Remove();
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Works fine with following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Events>
  <Event ID="1" >
    <SubEvent update="2013-02-05T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
    <SubEvent update="2013-03-08T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
  </Event>
  <Event ID="2">
    <SubEvent update="2013-01-05T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
    <SubEvent update="2013-01-05T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
    <SubEvent update="2013-02-05T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
  </Event>
  <Event ID="3">
    <SubEvent update="2013-03-05T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
    <SubEvent update="2013-04-05T17:06:23.8962976+03:00" />
  </Event>
</Events>
```

Comment: I'm curious why `Remove` in your sample works fine, but when I'm trying it inside my `foreach` like `el.Remove()` it only works for a first element?

Comment: @aush looks like enumeration breaks when document is modified. If you will do `query.ToList()` in foreach statement, then all will work fine. If you will not remove element (just enumerating, then all also fine). You maybe wonder why it works with `Enumerable<XElement>` extension? :) Because internally also new list of elements is created: `foreach (T local in new List<T>(source))`

Answer (score 0):

In suppose you're not missing a root of your xml

```
var xDoc = // your XDocument
var toDel = new List<XElement>();
foreach(var el in xDoc.Root.Elements("Event").Where(e => e.Elements("SubEvent").All(xel => xel.Attribute("update").Value == "DATETIME")))
{
    toDel.Add(el);
}
toDel.ForEach(e => e.Remove());
```

You have to replace the condition inside `.All()` to desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\input.xml");
        var x = new List<XElement>();
        foreach (var xElement in doc.Root.Elements("Event"))
        {
            DateTime maxDt = DateTime.MinValue;

            foreach (var element in xElement.Elements("SubEvent"))
            {
                var attributeValue = element.Attributes("update").FirstOrDefault();

                if (attributeValue == null) continue;

                DateTime dt;
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(attributeValue.Value, out dt)) continue;

                if (maxDt < dt) maxDt = dt;
            }

            xElement.RemoveNodes();
            xElement.Add(new XElement("SubEvent", new XAttribute("update", maxDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))));
            x.Add(new XElement(xElement));

        }

        new XDocument(new XElement("ev", x)).Save(@"D:\output.xml");
```